# Issue with a placing hamburger menu at the middle of iphone screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to place the hamburger menu at the middle of the webpage, but on iphone it's jumping on scrolling the page.

I'm using bootstrap 5.2 for it. The hamburger menu is placed at the center on the page, and looks good on desktop and android chrome, but on iphone it jumps on scrolling :(
I suppose, it happens because the url bar of the browser appears and disappears, but I don't understand why android chrome works correctly. Could you help me to resolve this issue?
It should look as on the screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Here is my html code:

```html
<nav class="navbar bg-light fixed-top top-50">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>         
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS, which you could be using for handling hamburger menu position? If yes, please add that to in your question.

Comment: I tried with and without custom CSS, but the result was the same. I left only the following CSS code:
```-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;```

Comment: here is the link for reproducing the issue:
https://www.webassiststudio.com/assets/navbar.html

Comment: Please put the code to repro the issue in the question, instead of referencing the external site. Questions should be useful to future readers, and when the external site changes over time, the question will be useless to future readers.

Comment: [here is the example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/krava77/pen/PoyOqEP)